# add font verdana into phpword

Tags: php, fonts, phpword

I am working with `phpword`, they have some default fonts like `arial`, `tims new roman`. I want to use font `verdana`.

After some research i got 1 `xml`, which contains the font part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:fonts xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:font w:name="Times New Roman"><w:panose1 w:val="02020603050405020304"/><w:charset w:val="00"/><w:family w:val="roman"/><w:pitch w:val="variable"/><w:sig w:usb0="E0002AFF" w:usb1="C0007841" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font><w:font w:name="Courier New"><w:panose1 w:val="02070309020205020404"/><w:charset w:val="00"/><w:family w:val="modern"/><w:pitch w:val="fixed"/><w:sig w:usb0="E0002AFF" w:usb1="C0007843" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font><w:font w:name="Wingdings"><w:panose1 w:val="05000000000000000000"/><w:charset w:val="02"/><w:family w:val="auto"/><w:pitch w:val="variable"/><w:sig w:usb0="00000000" w:usb1="10000000" w:usb2="00000000" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="80000000" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font><w:font w:name="Symbol"><w:panose1 w:val="05050102010706020507"/><w:charset w:val="02"/><w:family w:val="roman"/><w:pitch w:val="variable"/><w:sig w:usb0="00000000" w:usb1="10000000" w:usb2="00000000" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="80000000" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font><w:font w:name="Arial"><w:panose1 w:val="020B0604020202020204"/><w:charset w:val="00"/><w:family w:val="swiss"/><w:pitch w:val="variable"/><w:sig w:usb0="E0002AFF" w:usb1="C0007843" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font><w:font w:name="Cambria"><w:panose1 w:val="02040503050406030204"/><w:charset w:val="00"/><w:family w:val="roman"/><w:pitch w:val="variable"/><w:sig w:usb0="A00002EF" w:usb1="4000004B" w:usb2="00000000" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0000019F" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font><w:font w:name="Calibri"><w:panose1 w:val="020F0502020204030204"/><w:charset w:val="00"/><w:family w:val="swiss"/><w:pitch w:val="variable"/><w:sig w:usb0="E10002FF" w:usb1="4000ACFF" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0000019F" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font></w:fonts>
```

And if i convert 1 font into `json` array to see,

```
{
    "-w:name": "Calibri",
    "w:panose1": { "-w:val": "020F0502020204030204" },
    "w:charset": { "-w:val": "00" },
    "w:family": { "-w:val": "swiss" },
    "w:pitch": { "-w:val": "variable" },
    "w:sig": {
      "-w:usb0": "E10002FF",
      "-w:usb1": "4000ACFF",
      "-w:usb2": "00000009",
      "-w:usb3": "00000000",
      "-w:csb0": "0000019F",
      "-w:csb1": "00000000"
    }
  }
```

Its looks like this. Now i want to add font `verdana` so how can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this `xml` code

```
</w:font><w:font w:name="Verdana"><w:panose1 w:val="020B0604030504040204"/><w:charset w:val="00"/><w:family w:val="swiss"/><w:pitch w:val="variable"/><w:sig w:usb0="A10006FF" w:usb1="4000205B" w:usb2="00000010" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="0000019F" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font>
```